Prove that solution to geometric brownian motion is correct (plug into SDE)
As many previous questions/answers point out, the solution to the geometric brownian motion stochastic differential equation (GBM SDE)
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
dX_t &=& \mu X_t \,dt + \sigma X_t\,dW_t \\ 
X_0 &=& x_0
\end{array} 
\right.
\qquad(1)
$$
is
$$
X_t = x_0 \cdot \exp{\left\{\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}2\right)t + \sigma W_t\right\}} \qquad(2)
$$
I understand how to get the solution, using Itô's formula.
However, the question is how do you plug the solution $(2)$ into $(1)$ to get the equality. My approach is to integrate both sides of the first line of $(1)$:
$$
X_t = \mu \int_0^t X_u \,du + \sigma \int_0^{t} X_u\,dW_u + x_0 \qquad(3)
$$
As you can see, the problem here is to solve the two integrals that appear in $(3)$:
$$
\int_0^t X_u \,du = \int_0^t x_0 \cdot \exp{\left\{\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}2\right)u + \sigma W_u\right\}} \,du
$$
and
$$
\int_0^{t} X_u\,dW_u = \int_0^t x_0 \cdot \exp{\left\{\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}2\right)u + \sigma W_u\right\}} \,dW_u
$$
But I am stucked here. How do you solve the integrals considering they contain the Wiener process $W_t$ in the exponential?
EDIT:
As I understand from @Kakashi comment, I have to apply Itô's formula to the solution $X_t$:
$$
dX_t = \partial_t X_t\,dt+\partial_{W_t}X_t\,dW_t+ \frac12\partial_{W_t}^2 X_t (dW_t)^2\\
=\left(\mu-\frac{\sigma^2}2\right)X_t\,dt+\sigma X_t\,dW_t+\frac{\sigma^2}2X_t\,(dW_t)^2
$$
which gives the expression for the SDE, using $(dW_t)^2 = dt$:
$$
dX_t = \mu X_t \,dt + \sigma X_t\,dW_t
$$
So, the fact that with Itô's formula one arrives to the SDE from the proposed solution is a way to prove that is the correct one? Is this general?

The way you plug (2) to verify (1) is by Ito's formula. Rather, the derivation of the solution (2) from Ito's formula should be done so that (1) holds.

Hi @Kakashi, I edited the question including what I understood from what you said. Tell me if it is the right approach.

Make a guess $X_t = f (t, W_t)$ for the solution. By Ito's formula, omitting
the argument $(t, W_t)$,
\begin{eqnarray*}
  dX_t & = & f_t dt + f_w dW_t + \frac{1}{2} f_{w w} \cdot (dW_t)^2\\
  & = & f_t dt + f_w dW_t + \frac{1}{2} f_{w w} dt\\
  & = & \left( f_t + \frac{1}{2} f_{w w} \right) dt + f_w dW_t .
\end{eqnarray*}
So we want
\begin{eqnarray*}
  \left( f_t + \frac{1}{2} f_{w w} \right) dt + f_w dW_t & = & \mu fdt +
  \sigma fdW_t .
\end{eqnarray*}
This is equivalent to
\begin{eqnarray*}
  f_t + \frac{1}{2} f_{w w} & = & \mu f,\\
  f_w & = & \sigma f,
\end{eqnarray*}
this holding at $(t, W_t)$. Certainly we will get a solution if the above
holds for all $t > 0$ and $w \in \mathbb{R}$, so let's solve the PDE
\begin{eqnarray*}
  f_t (t, w) + \frac{1}{2} f_{w w} (t, w) & = & \mu f (t, w),\\
  f_w (t, w) & = & \sigma f (t, w) .
\end{eqnarray*}
Using the initial condition $f (0, 0) = X_0 = x_0$, you can solve the PDE
routinely to get
\begin{eqnarray*}
  f (t, w) & = & x_0 e^{\sigma w + \left( \mu - \frac{1}{2} \sigma^2 \right)
  t} .
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence $f (t, W_t)$ is a solution of the SDE. Notice the above proved that $f
(t, W_t)$ is a solution to the SDE, that is,
\begin{eqnarray*}
  f (t, W_t) & = & x_0 + \int_0^t \mu f (s, W_s) ds + \int_0^t \sigma f (s,
  W_s) dW_s, \quad t > 0.
\end{eqnarray*}
